# LoadRunner and encrypted URLs

Tags: loadrunner

When turning on encrypted urls on the app I am supposed to loadtest, even a single first navigation to a url is not possible to record. The browser that I am recording against gives me a page cannot be dispalyed.
Creating a manual web_url() function results in error. Below is both the script and the output log.
Anybody successfully managed to script against this kind of security technology before? And no using correlation does not solve this one since I do not even get to the first page.

```
Action()

{

    web_url("entrypoint", 

            "URL=http://e34jbsl00430.devillo.com:8080/entrypoint/", 

            "Resource=0", 

            "RecContentType=text/html", 

            "Referer=", 

            "Snapshot=t1.inf", 

            "Mode=HTML", 

            LAST);



    return 0;

}











Virtual User Script started at : 2013-04-16 17:15:30

Starting action vuser_init.

Web Turbo Replay of LoadRunner 11.0.0 for Windows 7; build 9375 (May 18 2011 01:44:32)   [MsgId: MMSG-27143]

Run Mode: HTML   [MsgId: MMSG-26000]

Run-Time Settings file: "C:\Users\F119506\AppData\Local\Temp\noname5\\default.cfg"       [MsgId: MMSG-27141]

Ending action vuser_init.

Running Vuser...

Starting iteration 1.

Starting action Action.

Action.c(4): Redirecting "http://e34jbsl00430.devillo.com:8080/entrypoint/" (redirection depth is 0)     [MsgId: MMSG-26694]

Action.c(4): To location "http://e34jbsl00430.devillo.com:8080/entrypoint/lL0pQMU3EnM;ENTRYPOINT_JSESSIONID=Z1s9WbTfYw0BW8LrXFckprZS"    [MsgId: MMSG-26693]

Action.c(4): Error -26627: HTTP Status-Code=404 (Not Found) for "http://e34jbsl00430.devillo.com:8080/entrypoint/lL0pQMU3EnM;ENTRYPOINT_JSESSIONID=Z1s9WbTfYw0BW8LrXFckprZS"     [MsgId: MERR-26627]

Action.c(4): web_url("entrypoint") highest severity level was "ERROR", 0 body bytes, 595 header     bytes, 5 chunking overhead bytes         [MsgId: MMSG-26387]

Ending action Action.

Ending iteration 1.

Ending Vuser...

Starting action vuser_end.
Ending action vuser_end.

Vuser Terminated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a header solved this:

web_add_header("Cookie"," JSESSIONID=dummy");

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is encrypted about the link.   It appears to be plain text, please clarify....

It does appear potentially to be a temporary redirected link where the redirection has disappeared at the end of a session.   I would be looking for how that dynamic component at the beginning is obtained or calculated using local code.

Comment: By the dynamic countent at the beginning, I guess you mean lL0pQMU3EnM, right?

Comment: The lL0pQMU3EnM is unique for every time I type the URL and press enter, entirely like a sessionid being added to the URL

Comment: I suspect some redirects happening "under the hood" results in this dynamic content being created in the URL. The log provided suggests this when it contains the keyword redirect?

Answer (score 0):

What are you typing in as the URI root to access?   have you considered changing the request and then allowing for the redirect to occur naturally from the HTTP header which is returned?

Comment: I type in http://e34jbsl00430.devillo.com:8080/entrypoint/ and press enter, then the dynamic/encrypted element is added to the URL before the first (log in page is displayed). Allowing for redirects? Set redirect depth? How do I tell VUGen to allow redirects naturally?

Comment: Your redirect is happening, but it is failing.   Check the web server logs for input from your web server admin.